# Relative homology generated by relative closed paths?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Take a nice topological space $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}X$. In particular path-connected and Hausdorff, but you can assume that it's a smooth manifold.

Take $p \in X$ arbitrary. We know that $H_1(X,\Z)$ is generated by (the cycles coming from) closed paths starting and ending at $p$. This can be seen for example from the Hurewicz theorem. (Or is there a simpler way to see it?)

Now take finitely many points $A \subset X$. I think that $H_1(X,A;\Z)$ is generated by (the relative cycles of) paths that start and end in $A$. But I don't know how to prove it.

I thought one can use that the map $f : X \to X/A$ induces an isomorphism $H_1(X,A;\Z) \cong H_1(X/A, A/A)$. The right hand side is generated by paths starting and ending at the point $A/A$ by what we have discussed before. But a priori this can't be represented on the left side by a single path. So I still need to lift a path in $X/A$ starting and ending at $A/A$ to a path in $X$ starting and ending within $A$. I'm not aware of any theorem around this, because it's not a covering map. For example: How to even choose the starting point in $A$ of the path? I don't think one can choose arbitrarily.

Can this be somehow turned into a proof, or is the statement true at all?

Edit: I think one could possibly adjust the proof of the Hurewicz theorem, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your space $X$ is [triangularizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)), the answer is "yes". It turns out that [every smooth manifold is triangularizable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangulation+theorem), so this covers your application of interest. You can almost certainly relax this assumption, but it makes the computation much easier.

Now, since $X$ is triangularizable and $A$ is a finite subset, fix a [simplicial structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex) whose geometric realization is homeomorphic to $X$, which has each point of $A$ as a vertex in the structure. Then $A$ becomes a *subcomplex*, so theorem $2.27$ in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* promises the relative singular homology $H_n(X,A)$ agrees with the relative simplicial homology $H_n^\Delta(X,A)$.

Here we define $C_n^\Delta(X)$ (resp. $A$) to be the formal sums of $n$-simplices in the simplicial complex $X$ (resp. $A$). We define the *relative* groups $C_n^\Delta(X,A) = C_n^\Delta(X) \big / C_n^\Delta(A)$, and let $H_n^\Delta(X,A)$ be the cohomology of this complex.

So in your case, we have

$$
H_1^\Delta(X,A) = 
\frac{\text{ker} \Big ( \partial : C_1^\Delta (X,A) \to C_0^\Delta (X,A) \Big )}
{\text{im} \Big ( \partial : C_2^\Delta (X,A) \to C_1^\Delta (X,A) \Big )}
$$

which is generated by chains in $\text{ker} \Big ( \partial : C_1^\Delta (X,A) \to C_0^\Delta (X,A) \Big )$. That is, chains whose boundary vanishes or whose boundary lies entirely in $A$. The benefit of switching to the simplicial setting is that now we can hit this over the head with combinatorics, and we don't need to worry about potential topological pathologies.

Let $\sum_{i < n} \sigma_i$ be a chain in this kernel. Say its boundary as computed in $C_1^\Delta(X)$ is nonzero.

Then there must be a point $a \in A$ in its boundary. Look at the simplex (without loss of generality $\sigma_1$) that contains $a$. If the other boundary point of $\sigma_1$ lies in $A$, then we're done. If not, then there's a simplex (without loss of generality $\sigma_2$) which shares this endpoint. Proceeding inductively, we'll add simplices until we eventually end in $A$ again. This must happen since our sum is finite and we know its boundary lies entirely in $A$. Say this is $\sum_{i < m} \sigma_i$.

Then we've decomposed our original chain into a simplicial path from $A$ to $A$, and a chain of smaller length. Inductively again, keep doing this until the boundary is empty. So we've decomposed our original chain into a sum of simplicial paths, plus a chain whose boundary is empty.

But then we can play a similar game, taking any $\sigma_i$ in this boundaryless chain and looking for the $\sigma_{i+1}$ that kills one of its boundary points. Since the sum is finite and the total boundary is $0$, we must eventually get back to $\sigma_i$, so that we have a simplicial loop. We can, of course, repeat this as necessary.

So every chain in the kernel of $\text{ker} \Big ( \partial : C_1^\Delta (X,A) \to C_0^\Delta (X,A) \Big )$ decomposes as a finite sum of simplicial paths whose endpoints are in $A$ and simplicial loops. Thus, the loops and the simplicial paths with endpoints in $A$ generate $H_1^\Delta(X,A)$.

Of course, each loop is homologous to a (degenerate) loop that goes through $A$. Indeed, if $\sum_{i < n} \sigma_i$ is a simplicial loop, let $x$ be one of the boundary points of $\sigma_1$. Then by connectedness there's a simplicial path $\sum_{j < m} \sigma_j'$ from $x$ to some $a \in A$, so
$\left ( \sum_i \sigma_i \right ) + \left ( \sum_j \sigma_j' \right ) - \left ( \sum_j \sigma_j' \right )$ is a (denegerate) simplicial loop which obviously equals the loop we started with, but which is "based in $A$".

So then $H_1^\Delta(X,A)$ is generated by the simplicial paths and loops based in $A$!

Lastly, the isomorphism $H_1^\Delta(X,A) \cong H_1(X,A)$ is given by geometric realization. So the generators of $H_1^\Delta(X,A)$ get sent to generators of $H_1(X,A)$ under this isomorphism, but simplicial paths/loops based in $A$ get sent to honest paths/loops based in $A$!

So we see that, indeed, $H_1(X,A)$ is generated by paths and loops based in $A$. This is unsurprising, since this is how working topologists think about $H_1$!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for all this effort! I think though there is a misunderstanding. As you beautifully explained, it's clear directly from the definition that my relative homology group is generated by *chains* whose boundary lies in $A$. But what I want to prove is that it's generated by *1-simplices* whose boundary is in A, which is really not obvious.

Comment: For example, take $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $A = \{0,20\}$. Write $[a,b]$ for the chain which is representing a path from $a$ to $b$. Then $[0,3] + [3,7] + [7,20]$ is a chain with boundary in $A$. What I want to prove is that it can be written as a sum of paths that on their own (!) start and end in $A$. In this case, the chain is homologous to $[0,20]$.

Comment: @JohannBirnick -- ah, you're right. I did misunderstand. Give me one second to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That should indeed work in more generality, directly working with singular simplices.